# Mailchimp Sync CiviCRM Extension: Two-way sync is not working

Tags: extension, mailchimp

When running a **sync** between Mailchimp and CiviCRM, I only get **added to CiviCRM** the new subscribers in MailChimp, but the new contacts/members or changes in CiviCRM **never migrate into Mailchimp**.

I've got installed **CiviCRM 5.21.1** and I've tested it with **Mailchimp Sync CiviCRM extension** that can be found in *https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimpsync*

*https://docs.civicrm.org/mailchimpsync/en/latest*

Any help will be very much appreciated.